# Installing Solidity Dependencies with Foundry

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, openzeppelin

I can't build my smart contract using Foundry because my dependency isn't recognized.

According to the documentation I have run the command

`forge install openzeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts`

Then I added the following line in the remapping.txt file:

`openzeppelin-contracts/=lib/openzeppelin/contracts/`

After updating the remapping file I ran the command and below are the results:
`forge remappings`

[image]

Now when I create my simple ERC20 contract that has the following code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
contract Grape is ERC20, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC20("Grape", "GRP") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }
function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}
```

And I try to build my project using:
`forge build`

It doesn't build correctly:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Foundry remapping file name should be "remappings.txt" not "remapping.txt"

And add `@openzeppelin/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/` to remappings.txt.

Answer (score -2):

When installing openzeppelin contracts use

```
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts
```

After installing youll have node_modules folder. And as i presume you have contracts in src folder, so to connect openzeppelin contracts you should put correct path for every single file you import, like this:

```
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

Comment: The question indicates using foundry. Using npm is a whole different solution.